# Execute Command from docker on host

Tags: docker, opensuse

I do have a few question but first I want to explain what I am trying to do. I am working on creating my own mirror for the opensuse repositories with rsync. This is already tested and works so far. 
Sometimes there is a problem with e.g. the "repomd.xml" which is unsigned or invalid. I recognize that if I do "zypper refresh" with the original repositories from download.opensuse.org, I can detect problems with the original mirror. In that case, I do not want to rsync, so I thought I would just test it everytime before I rsync. It works so far.

Now this construct needs to be in docker. I configured a server and do the script with rsync in a while loop. I do know that this is against docker policy and not the best solution for doing some kind of cron job in docker.

The problem is now, that I cant just do "zypper refresh" because in docker is ubuntu. Is there a possibilty to execute "zypper refresh" from docker on the host and the result gets back into docker, so I can work with?

I only need to know if the command finished with zero or non-zero.

Comment: Why you are using a ubuntu image and not a opensuse image : https://hub.docker.com/r/opensuse/leap  or https://hub.docker.com/r/opensuse/tumbleweed ?

Comment: I assume that I would not get the error with a leap in docker because the repos would be already up to date. That's why I want to do it on the host instead of using Opensuse.